# Sorting values of Dict

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

```
for y in item:
    print '%s %s %s' % (item[y]['light'], item[y]['time'], item[y]['name'])
```

yields:

```
10.38002 2.95000 earth
10.38000 12.04000 earth
10.28865 0.09789 earth
9.90000 12.50000 earth
9.77063 3.51299 earth
9.77000 13.40000 earth
10.38000000 1.26523000 moon
10.36000000 65.80305000 moon
10.31000000 1.72639000 moon
10.30000000 2.00000000 moon
10.33726 0.09833000 jupiter
10.30938 0.16622000 jupiter
10.24001 0.34554000 jupiter
10.24000 11.82214802 jupiter
10.23389 0.10840000 jupiter
10.20629 0.17732000 jupiter
```

I would like to sort the items based on the first key: 'light'.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You mean you would like to sort by value (of the key 'light'). Have you searched StackOverflow for sorting a dictionary? There are lots of good answers already.

Comment: i've tried many answers. i'm trying to convert to list now, then do thikonom's [constructive!] answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should convert it to a list and then:

```
  item.sort(key=lambda x: x['light'])
```

Comment: `item` is a `dict`, which has no `sort` member.

Comment: i thought it is a list: x = [{'light': 1, 'time': 2, 'name': 'name'}]

Comment: works very nicely, thanks! sorry for the beginner's question though!

Answer (score 1):

```
res = sorted(item.values(), key = lambda x: x['light'] )
for x in res: 
    print '%s %s %s' % (x['light'], x['time'], x['name'])
```